# input controls for easy filtering in kibana dashboard?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have successfully used kibana (4.3.1) to make a dashboard with several visualizations. Great! Now I would like to add some input controls to allow filtering. I know that you can manually enter filters in the query bar, for example 'myCol:[low TO high]' but this is problematic for a couple of reasons. First, the syntax is a little too advanced for casual users (although I could use the metadata visualization to document the syntax). Second, the query bar goes away when exporting the dashboard via iframe.

I have tried using the metric visualization to display a min and max values. Unfortunately, the metric visualization is read only.

I have tried a bar chart to allow range filtering but my users will need to select very specific ranges that result in selection areas of only a few pixels. This is error prone and not precise enough.

Any other ideas on how to create input controls for easy filtering? I was hoping find some sort of dial that is tied to a column to allow users an easy way to apply filters.

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 1):

Check [working with filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/visualize.html#visualize-filters) section in the documentation. Selecting a filter changes dashboard URL and includes snippet like `(filters:!((meta:(disabled:!t,index:'myIndex_*',key:MyTermToFilter,negate:!f,value:'MyValueToFilter')`. Once you have all the filters you want your users to change in the URL, after they navigate to that URL they will be able to enable/disable them in the UI

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. One follow up question - how do you turn a search in the toolbar search field into one of these filter widgets?

Comment: I always created a visualization first (search query is included into visualization in case you need it), then added visualization to a dashboard, then clicked on an item, which makes filter available on a dashboard. I believe filter is not tied to a visualization (you can delete visualization after you have a filter), but I did not try it

Comment: Is there any way to edit the filter other than updating the raw JSON?